# How can I delay start-up based on time of day?

Tags: startup

I have a bad habit of spending too much time on my computer at night when I should be sleeping. In the past, shutting down my computer was an effective way to enforce a no-technology bedtime on myself. However, I just upgraded to an ultrabook which takes only a few seconds to boot and I no longer have the disincentive to avoid restarting my computer.

I would like to have a Python script or something that programmatically delays log-in for a  set period of time depending on the time of day. For example, no delay if starting the computer during normal working hours, but if I try to start the system up at 10:00pm, I would like it to count down for five minutes or so before allowing me to log-in.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 if this makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a script which is run by lightdm when you login. e.g:

```
#!/bin/bash
if ((`date +%H` >= 20)); then
    sleep 10
fi
```

The above script will cause a 10 sec delay if the you try to login between 20:00 and 23:59. Make the script executable and place it somewhere, e.g ~/bin/login_script

To make it run by lightdm edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and add the following line:

```
session-setup-script=/home/myuser/bin/login_script
```